# Can a contract do something on the condition that there's enough gas?

Tags: solidity, gas

Can a contract have a method that, does something, and if there is gas left over, performs an extra task?

Something like:

```
function doSomething() {
  performCheapTask();
  if(thereIsGasLeftOver) {
    performExtraTask();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can check `gasleft()` to get the remaining gas and only proceed if you think you'll have enough. This assumes you can make a reasonable estimate of how much gas you'll need, though: If you undershoot and spend too much, the whole transaction will be reverted.

There's some related discussion under this EIP: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/90

Also note that there are proposals to change the gas requirements in a future fork, so even if you estimate the gas you need correctly now, it may break in future.